# Insert data into one of a number of spares stock cards

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a set of spares stock control cards (68 individual cards) which have inputs in column “B” for the Quantity Sold and column “C” for the date sold. The quantity and dates are to be picked up from cells “P1” for the Quantity and “Q1” for the date.

The spares stock card to be selected for the input comes from cell “R7”. This cell gives the item number. (i.e. The card number to have an entry made.)

The existing macro selects the right stock card numbered in range “R7” and places the cursor on the first entry row in column “B”.

I now want to enter the quantity sold and the date in the next empty cell down.

I cannot get the cursor to move beyond `Worksheets("Nail Cards").Range("C2:C4012").Find(Range("R7").Value).Offset(8, -1).Select`.

I thought the following last part of the macro would input the data into the appropriate cells but does not appear to activate.

```vb
    Lrow = Worksheets("Nail Cards").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Worksheets("Nail Cards").Range("B" & Lrow & ":C" & Lrow) = Worksheets("Nail Cards").Range("P1:Q1").Value
End Sub
```

A portrayal of a spares stock control card.
[image]

Comment: `I cannot get the cursor to move beyond` - why? What happens instead?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be close to what you're trying to do:

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, c As Range, itmNum
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Nail Cards")
    
    itmNum = ws.Range("R7").Value
    Set c = ws.Range("C2:C4012").Find(itmNum)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        'I use 50 here but use actual # of data entry rows per card
        Set c = c.Offset(8, -1).Resize(50).Find("", searchdirection:=xlNext)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            c.Resize(1, 2).Value = ws.Range("P1:Q1").Value
        Else
            'no empty slot
            MsgBox "Card #" & ws.Range("R7").Value & "  is full!", vbExclamation
        End If
    Else
        'card was not found
        MsgBox "Card #" & ws.Range("R7").Value & "  not found!", vbExclamation
    End If
End Sub
```